What is 1433U used for in MSSQL?
Investigating a freak interface flood hindering other traffic on 1433U inbound I found that legitimate traffic is on 1433T for DB traffic, 1434U for instance browsing, 1434T for admin access.
But: looking into services I see the installation did register 1433U for MSSQL server.
To what purpose?
ms-sql-s         1433/tcp                           #Microsoft-SQL-Server 
ms-sql-s         1433/udp                           #Microsoft-SQL-Server 
ms-sql-m         1434/tcp                           #Microsoft-SQL-Monitor
ms-sql-m         1434/udp                           #Microsoft-SQL-Monitor     

What might flood 1433U?


looking into services I see the installation did register 1433U for
MSSQL server.
ms-sql-s         1433/udp                           #Microsoft-SQL-Server


This entry was not created during SQL Server installation. The %SystemRoot%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services file installed with Windows contains UDP port 1433 and many other INAA registered port numbers.
I believe Microsoft reserved UDP port 1433 with INAA many years ago but is not currently using it. The SQL Server port documentation does not include UDP port 1433.
